# GC ImageMagick Trim Max Width & Heigh

Tags: google-cloud-platform, imagemagick, google-cloud-functions

I'm using ImageMagick in Google Cloud, but I believe its just an interface for the CLI version.

What I'm trying to do is trim off any transparency and then resize the image to a maximum of 190px wide and 230px tall.

I've successfully got it working so the images are no bigger than 190px wide, but I can't figure out how to also set a maximum height.

Any ideas?
This is how I am currently setting the width:

```
  return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-trim','-resize', '190', tempFilePath]);
```

Comment: It's not just an interface - it *is* the CLI version you're invoking.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't realise that the dimensions passed were maximums if using resize:

```
  return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-trim','-resize', '190x230', tempFilePath]);
```

This will resize to a max of 190 width or 230 high whilst keeping the ratio